# Android ProgressDialog "Spinner" disappear(doesn't show up)

Tags: android, android-layout, progressdialog, android-progressbar

I'm working on an android app and I need to fetch data from internet.
I declare an "private Progress dialog" in Homepage.java.
In onCreate() method, call the function

```
 dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Homepage.this, "Connecting", "Please wait for a while...", true);
```

And create another thread to fetch the data, and in finally block, call

```
 "dialog.dismiss()"
```

The whole onResume() code is shown in below.

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Homepage.this, "Connecting", "Please wait for a while..", true);

    /******Start fetching data.******/
    Thread getDataThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                try {
                    getData();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    alert_error();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    alert_error();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                alert_error();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                alert_error();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                alert_error();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
    getDataThread.start();
}
```

At first, this worked great.(the spinner showed)
But at some point(I don't remember when), the dialog still works, but the spinner disappear
Show as below(place marked with red line should be the place where spinner display)
[Spinner is gone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzNsv.png)

The dialog still works, but all ProgressDialog called anywhere from this app, the spinner is gone.(not even show up)

If I changed the getting data from internet part to sleeping for 10 secs
Which is shown below

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Homepage.this, "Connecting", "Please wait for a while...", true);

    /******Start fetching data.******/
Thread getDataThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                sleep(10*1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                dialog.dismiss;
            }
        }
    };

    getDataThread.start();

}
```

The spinner still doesn't show up.

I think that might be something related to global settings or values in my project, I create a empty activity with only one method other than    super.onCreate and setContentView
I called
"ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Homepage.this, "123", "456", true);"

and the spinner still doesn't show up!

But if I create a new project and added the same code, it works!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post your class where you are opening spinner and fetching data so that one can help.

Comment: Show your code here

Comment: Code added. Due to privacy concerns and security issues of this app, I can't show the remaining part . But other than this activity(Homepage.java), any other activities face the same problem, which is the spinner is gone.

Comment: The remaining part doesn't relate to the ProgressDialog.

Comment: You have problem with showing spinner, but didn't included code related to that. you are only showing fetching data code. Where are you populating spinner show that code.

Comment: Spinner and progress dialog are two different things

Comment: @VivekMishra
I thought ProgressDialog contains a spinner by default?

Comment: @abdulkhan
Sorry, can you be more specific?
In line 4, I called "ialog = ProgressDialog.show(Homepage.this, "Connecting", "Please wait for a while...", true);"

Comment: I think is something related to global settings or values in my project, I create a empty activity with only one method other than  super.onCreate and setContentView
I called
"ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Homepage.this, "123", "456", true);"
and the spinner still doesn't show up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is in your phone setting, I had the same issue once, what you need to do is:

Go to developer options in your phone setting.

Turn transition on (in my case i had them turned off to make the phone act fast)

Restart the app and hopefully spinner will be there.

**UPDATE:**

Or you can try a library like [Material Dialogs](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) for that purpose, its one of my favorites, all you need to do is

Compile

```
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.0'
```

and then where you want to show the dialog

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
    .title(R.string.progress_dialog)
    .content(R.string.please_wait)
    .progress(true, 0)
    .show();
```

you can find more info [here](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) to customize it further and usage details.

Hope it helps

Comment: I checked and it seems already turn on.
If I create a new project, the spinner would display.
But this projects has dozens of activities and many settings and properties, it would take lots of time to switch all this files to new project.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: By the way, whether I run on my HTC ONE or emulator, the spinner just doesn't show up.

Comment: try this `dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Homepage.this, "Connecting", "Please wait for a while...", true, true);`

Comment: Doesn't work either. But thanks! Really Appreciate it.

Comment: Glad I could help, always mark the answer as complete and upvote good answers so if anyone else has the same problem they would know where to find the solution.